# Convert a wrong JSON string to JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have this wrong Json string:

> ({loc: '(49.150892549035454, 9.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'Otest', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loa', gender: 'male'});
>   ({loc: '(12.150892549035454, 12.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'OtestRe', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loaa', gender: 'female'});

So now I tried to correct the string with:

```
        var res = this.markerlist.replace(/\)|\(/g, '');
        var res2 = res.replace(/;/g, ',');
        var jsonList = JSON.stringify('[' + res2 + ']';
```

> [{loc: '(49.150892549035454, 9.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'Otest', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loa', gender: 'male'},
>   ({loc: '(12.150892549035454, 12.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'OtestRe', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loaa', gender: 'female'}]

Then I try to parse it:

```
   var jsonRs = JSON.parse(jsonList);


     for (var rowData in jsonRs) // for acts as a foreach
    {
        console.log(jsonRs[rowData]);

    }
```

And I get every character as output like:

```
4
9
.
1
```

And so on.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You should use JSON.parse not JSON.stringify.

Comment: You should not iterate over an array with `for... in` but with `for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)`

Comment: That data must be conforming to some defined syntax. What is that syntax? Isn't there a parser available for it? Must be a better way than trying to convert it to JSON data.

Comment: It seems like you are using a JSONP service and you forgot the `callback` URL parameter. Like this: `http://example/com/get.json?callback=test`

Comment: oh damn @Ismael Miguel  is right thx

Comment: @user3387996 You want me to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although as everyone suggested, knowing the format is important to solve your problem. So your approach to replace & parse is wrong & error prone.

Your **Json string** is actually javascript... So even an eval could work.

**EDIT :** As pointed out by Biwise Creative, it would need bit of treatment :

```
this.markerlist.split(";").slice(0,-1).map(function(t) {return eval(t);})
```

Comment: This won't work well with his string as-is since there are multiple objects. He'll end up with a single object with the values of the last data set. You'd still need to split and format the string data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your input like this:

```
var input = "({loc: '(49.150892549035454, 9.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'Otest', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loa', gender: 'male'}); ({loc: '(12.150892549035454, 12.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'OtestRe', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loaa', gender: 'female'});";

var result = input
             .split(";") // spliting ';' for each object
             .slice(0, -1) // removing last portion after ';'
             .map(function(item) {
                 var cleaned = item
                     .trim() // removing white spaces from the ends
                     .slice(1, -1) // getting rid of ()
                     .replace(/'/g, '"') // replacing ' to "
                     .replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":'); // surrounding word before ':' with double quotes
                 return JSON.parse(cleaned);
             });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another version with `loc` property as Array so you could use  `lattitude` ang `longitude`

```
 var markerlist = "({loc: '(49.150892549035454, 9.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'Otest', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loa', gender: 'male'}); ({loc: '(12.150892549035454, 12.22825813293457)' , shopName: 'OtestRe', nameID: '1', apID: 'Loaa', gender: 'female'});";

    var arStr = markerlist.split(";");
    var jsons = [];

    for(var i=0;i < arStr.length;i++){
            var o = eval(arStr[i]);
                    if(o){
                            o.loc = o.loc
                                    .replace(/\(|\)/g, "")
                                    .split(',');
                            jsons.push(o);
                    }
    }
    console.log(jsons);
```